# Intellij Idea: how to put dollar sign to the replaced content

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, replace

When You have a replace and you want to replace text with something that contains $ You get a malformed replacement string (interpreter thinks its a variable reference). The $$ doesn't work.

Comment: Ensure that `Regex` is not marked when you replace.

Comment: hmm - ok but what if I am actually using regex ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As featured in [Regular Expression Syntax Reference](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/regular-expression-syntax-reference.html) - you can use `\\$` to escape $ sign.

Answer (score 2):

`\ $1`
if IDE from JetBrains you need type space character between slash and sign dollar